# Setting axis limits for matrix projection

Tags: matlab, plot, axis

I am projecting the values of a matrix using imagesc. I want to set the X-axis limits between [0:22000] seconds. I wrote a sample code for this. It's not working as expected. Any help will be appreciated.

```
cars_in_field = cell2mat(cars_in_field);
cars_in_garage = cell2mat(cars_in_garage);
cars_in_workshop = cell2mat(cars_in_workshop);

all_area_for_visual= 
cars_in_field+2*cars_in_garage+3*cars_in_workshop
figure()
imagesc(transpose(all_area_for_visual));
colormap("jet")
xlim([0 ,22000])
```

[image];
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
figure
imagesc(transpose(all_area_for_visual));
colormap("jet");
xlim([0 22000]);
```

Comment: I tried this before. But the graph itself seems to change with this.

Comment: Then you can add that to your post and the output after using xlim.

Comment: this is how it looks now.

Comment: it's because of the limit. Are you lokking for [0 220000]?